# Solving $(y\cos x)dx+(\sin x +2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Greetings my teacher gave me the following differential equation: $$(y\cos x)dx+(\sin x +2)dy=0$$ and told me it's an total differential equation and to solve in $y(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ so I have two possible solutions and I 
 dont know which one is correct. Let's denote $P(x,y)$ to be the coefficients of $dx$ and $Q(x,y)$ to be the coeffiecients of dy. Firstly using: $$u(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^x P(t,y_0)dt +\int_{y_0}^y Q(x,t)dt$$ gives $$u(x,y)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{2}\cos{t}dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^y \sin{x}dt=\frac{1}{2}\sin{x}+y\sin{x}-\frac{1}{2}\sin{x}=y\sin{x}$$ And the second method would be to use: $$u(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^x P(t,y)dt +\int_{y_0}^y Q(x_0,t)dt$$ which gives: $$u(x,y)=\int_0^x y\cos{t}dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^y (\sin{0}+2)dt=y\sin{x}+2y-1$$ Also one can notice that is in fact also a separable differential equation.
Which one is correct and what shall I use? Edit: The only problem was that I forgot to put $+2$ in the second integral for the first method..

Comment: Why don't you just check the total differential of your solutions to see which one is right?
When you've done that, you can probably also spot the mistake you made in the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather do it like this;

$(y\cos x)dx+(\sin x +2)dy=0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = - \dfrac{y\cos(x)}{\sin(x)+2}$

$\dfrac{dy}{y}= \dfrac{-\cos(x)dx}{\sin(x)+2}$

$\displaystyle\int\frac{dy}{y}=\int\frac{-\cos(x)\,dx}{\sin(x)+2}$

$\displaystyle\ln(y) = -\ln\big(\sin(x)+2\big)+\ln C$

$y= \dfrac{C}{\sin(x)+2}$

$y(0) =\dfrac 12$

$\implies \dfrac12 = \dfrac{C}{2}\implies C=1$

$\therefore y=\dfrac1{\sin(x)+2}$

Comment: but are they equal? or the purpose of the differential equation is to find only one solution?

Comment: @Dahaka well since youre given initial conditions , youll get one solution. Also the solutions you've managed to find dont seem to be equal

Comment: see my edit. It was just a silly mistake and they are equal

Comment: @Dahaka I'd advise you to use separable variable method, since that is quite frankly the easiest and less prone to silly mistakes

Answer (score 3):

Make the ODE into other form $$a\frac{dy}{dx} + b = 0$$ with functions $a = a(x,y) = \sin x + 2$ and $b = b(x,y) = y\cos x$. They have relation $$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = \cos x = \frac{\partial b}{\partial y}$$ which is necessary condition of exact ODE. So setting function $$\psi(x,y) = \int dy\ \sin x + 2 = \int dx\ y\cos x$$ such it have form $$\psi(x,y) = y\sin x + 2y$$ in ODE $$\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x,y) = 0.$$
Therefore the general solution of the exact ODE come here $$y = \frac{c}{\sin x + 2}$$ with real constant $c$ of integral.
In the initial condition $y_0 = y(0) = 2^{-1}$, the real constant $c$ is $1$, and the solution become $$y = \frac{1}{\sin x + 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\partial_x F=(y\cos x) \implies F=\int y\cos xdx=y\sin x +\phi(y)$$
$$\partial_y F=\sin x +2=0 \implies F=\int \sin x +2)dy=2y+y\sin x +\psi (x)$$
$$ \implies F=2y+y\sin x   \implies 2y+y\sin x =C$$

---

**Another solution**...
$$(y\cos x)dx+(\sin x +2)dy=0$$
$$(y\cos x)+(\sin x +2)y'=0$$
$$(y\sin x)'+2y'=0$$
Integrate 
$$(y\sin x)+2y=K$$
$$\implies y=\frac K {\sin x +2}$$